# How to group a list of tuples based on the strings they contain?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a sorted list of two-string tuples. I also have another list of 4 character strings that are in some of those tuples. I would like to group from one of these 4 character strings to the next in the list. It is a bit hard to explain so I will demonstrate.

```
original_list = [('1321', 01), ('MessageXZY', 02), ('DescriptionSKS', 03), ('S7_6', 04), ('S7_3', 05), ('0A3B', 06), ('MessageZYA', 07),
 ('DescriptionKAM', 08), ('9K44', 09), ('MessageYAL', 10),
 ('DescriptionAUS', 11), ('S7_2', 12)]
```

I have the terms **1321**, **OA3B** and **9K44** saved in another list. I would like to group everything between (and including) these terms into a tuple, like so:

```
grouped_list = [(('1321', 01), ('MessageXZY', 02), ('DescriptionSKS', 03), ('S7_6', 04), ('S7_3', 05)), (('0A3B', 06), ('MessageZYA', 07),
 ('DescriptionKAM', 08)), (('9K44', 09), ('MessageYAL', 10),
 ('DescriptionAUS', 11), ('S7_2', 12))]
```

If the list that contains my 4 character terms is called **code** and the list containing the tuples is called **original_list**, what code would I need to achieve this?

Edit: This is where I have gotten up to:

```
grouped_list = []
for tuple in original_list:
    for string in tuple:
        if string in code:
            grouped_list = list(zip ##zip that tuple and all consecutive tuples until the next item in code
```

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking for. Perhaps a simple example and some code showing your effort will be good.

Comment: Its not clear , include your second list and post expected input and output clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you have list of codes with which you want to split on. According to that see if this code works for you.

```
original_list = [('1321', '01'), ('MessageXZY', '02'), ('DescriptionSKS', '03'), ('S7_6', '04'), ('S7_3', '05'), ('0A3B', '06'), ('MessageZYA', '07'), ('DescriptionKAM', '08'), ('9K44', '09'), ('MessageYAL', '10'),
 ('DescriptionAUS', '11'), ('S7_2', '12')]

code_list = ['1321', '0A3B','9K44']


grouped_tuples = []
for entry in original_list:
    if entry[0] in code_list:
        new_tuple = []
        new_tuple.append(entry)
        for i in range(original_list.index(entry)+1, len(original_list)):
            if(original_list[i][0] not in code_list):
                new_tuple.append(original_list[i])
            else:
                break
        grouped_tuples.append(tuple(new_tuple))
print grouped_tuples
```

Comment: It seems that has removed the 4 character terms (those in code_list) from the original list. All I really need to do is put in some more brackets in certain spots of the original_list, starting from a tuple that contains a 4 character term in the code_list until the next tuple containing a 4 character term.

Comment: @david_10001: The output looks correct to me. Or at least, similar to what you wrote the output should be.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I had a mistake in my preceding code. Thank you for your help

Comment: I had this working but I then altered some of the strings in this list and am now getting    grouped_tuples.append(tuple(new_tuple))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable   . I have triple checked every tuple of list and they are the exact same length as before, so I don't know what would be causing this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Coming from a Ruby background, I often felt the need to use something like [`Enumerable#slice_before`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) in Python. It basically splits any iterable into chunks. The slice is done before every element for which the predicate is true.

Based on the [Rubinius implementation](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/enumerable.rb#L136), I ported the code to Python.

```
def slice_before(iterable, predicate):
    chunk = None
    for elem in iter(iterable):
        if predicate(elem):
            if chunk:
                yield chunk
            chunk = [elem]
        else:
            if not chunk:
                chunk = []
            chunk.append(elem)
    if chunk:
        yield chunk
```

Here are a few examples:

```
>>> list(slice_before(range(12), lambda i: i % 3 == 0))
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
>>> list(slice_before('LetsTestSliceBefore', str.isupper))
[['L', 'e', 't', 's'], ['T', 'e', 's', 't'], ['S', 'l', 'i', 'c', 'e'], ['B', 'e', 'f', 'o', 'r', 'e']]
```

You just need to initialize your data. Note that `code_list` could be a set for faster lookup:

```
original_list = [('1321', '01'), ('MessageXZY', '02'), ('DescriptionSKS', '03'), ('S7_6', '04'), ('S7_3', '05'), ('0A3B', '06'), ('MessageZYA', '07'), ('DescriptionKAM', '08'), ('9K44', '09'), ('MessageYAL', '10'),
 ('DescriptionAUS', '11'), ('S7_2', '12')]

code_list = {'1321', '0A3B','9K44'}
```

The required code for your problem becomes a one-liner with `slice_before`:

```
print(list(slice_before(original_list, lambda x_y: x_y[0] in code_list)))
# [[('1321', '01'), ('MessageXZY', '02'), ('DescriptionSKS', '03'), ('S7_6', '04'), ('S7_3', '05')], [('0A3B', '06'), ('MessageZYA', '07'), ('DescriptionKAM', '08')], [('9K44', '09'), ('MessageYAL', '10'), ('DescriptionAUS', '11'), ('S7_2', '12')]]
```

Comment: How do I get code_list into that format with the curly brackets?

Comment: @david_10001: I'm not sure I understand the question. If you have a list `['1321', '0A3B','9K44']` and want a set : you can write `set(['1321', '0A3B','9K44'])` or directly `{'1321', '0A3B','9K44'}`

Comment: Yes I have tried using set(code_list) and then print (code_list) and it prints out just the same as before.

Comment: @david_10001: Yes. The only difference is that it's much faster to check if a string is inside a set than inside a list.

Comment: Oh okay. I have used the above code but am still seeing the index numbers with each tuple. I noticed you also have that in the output in your example. I am trying to remove them from list.

Comment: @david_10001: The output looks like what you said the output should look like, right?

Comment: The output using this code is the exact same as the original_list. In your example it is the exact same as well.